# Problems with Debian VM - import ZFS pool state: UNAVAILABLE

Tags: debian, zfs, proxmox

I had created RAIDZ1 pool in Proxmox. I had created Ubuntu VM and passed the controller with disks to it. After little while I wanted to try Debian. I had removed the controller from Ubuntu VM without any "zpool export" and I had deleted VM . Now I had done similar things- created Debian VM, passsed the controller to it, install zfs fuse and wanted to mount my pool.
I got error like this:

state: UNAVAIL
status: The pool was last accessed by another system.
action: The pool cannot be imported due to damaged devices or data.
   see: http://www.sun.com/msg/ZFS-8000-EY

What should I do? I dont have any important data on it yet but I want to know how to fix it and avoid any future problems.

Comment: see [this](https://zfsonlinux.org/msg/ZFS-8000-EY/). try importing with `zpool import poolname -f`

Comment: Thanks :)  -f  solved the problem